# Functional Programming in Scala exercises guidance

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I have been using Scala as a means to learn Functional Programming and writing better code. However, I have some questions regarding some exercises or if there's a better way to approach them.

Below are some exercises and my solutions/insights/doubts:

HARD - Write a function that concatenates a list of lists into a single list. Its runtime should be linear in the total length of all lists. Try to use functions we have already defined.

My sol:

```
//concatenates list of lists in a single list
def concatLists(x: List[List[Int]]):List[Int] = x.foldLeft( List[Int]() )( (x,y)=> x ++ y )
```

I have the feeling that the use of foldLeft and the concatenation operator is the right way to go and the runtime feels linear because we are appending one element at a time to the result of the fold, so the time is linear in the input size, am I right? Or is the ++ operator not efficient due to the List being implemented as a linked list? If not, how can I improve this?

EXERCISE 16: Write a function that transforms a list of integers by adding 1
to each element. (Reminder: this should be a pure function that returns a new
List !) AND 
EXERCISE 18: Write a function map , that generalizes modifying each element in a list while maintaining the structure of the list. Here is its signature: def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B]

```
//Adds one - exercise 16
def add1(x:List[Int]):List[Int]= for(elem <- x) yield elem+1

//implements map - exercise 18
def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B]=for(elem <- l) yield f(elem)
```

I've used yield before in some "toy exercises" in sites like hackerrank and similar and from my understanding, it is used in sequence comprehensions and adds a new element to the resulting sequence, much like in Python and the sequence assumes the return type declared in the function signature, is this correct?

What I want to know is if these implementations are correct in functional terms or if there are other/better ways of writing them.

EDIT: Already "defined" functions in previous exercises were: foldLeft, foldRight,append, sum, product, head and tail

Comment: Better suited for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A `foldLeft` is indeed the right solution. To improve your code, it may be useful to know that there are 2 variants of concatenation operations, one of which is specific to List.

`List` is one of the few collections who got to keeps its original functionally oriented `:::` operator after Scala 2.8. You can now add all collections with `++`, including `Iterator`, however they bear a small problem.

With lists, you should always prefer `:::`. There are two reasons: efficiency and type safety around the collection type.

**Efficiency**

`x ::: y ::: z` is faster than `x ++ y ++ z`, because `:::` is right associative. `x ::: y ::: z` is parsed as `x ::: (y ::: z)`, which is algorithmically faster than `(x ::: y) ::: z`, as the latter variant requires O(|x|) more steps).

**Enforcing type-safety**

The `++` introduced in Scala 2.8 allows you do add any 2 collections together, which can lead to very interesting things.

```
scala> List(4, 5) ++ "ab"
res0: List[AnyVal] = List(4, 5, a, b)
```

The `:::` operator will however correctly enforce both the inner type and collection type. The right associativity makes them semantically different, as `++` will `append` whereas `:::` will "prepend".

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) ++ List(4, 5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The `:::` will act differently, as the call is evaluated on the right hand side.

```
scala> List(4, 5) ::: List(1, 2, 3)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**Conclusion**

```
def concatLists(
  x: List[List[Int]]
): List[Int] = (x :\ List.empty[T]) { (acc, l) => acc ::: l }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the purpose of the assignment is to use the build in functions of scala but more to implement them by yourself - using the beauty of functional programming.

For the list concat, I would say you could try a tail-recursive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) approach.

```
def concatLists(x: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def concat(accu: List[Int], rest: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
      rest match {
        case Nil => accu
        case head :: tail => concat(head ++ accu,tail)
      }
    }
    concat(Nil,x)
  }
```

Note: the tailrec annotation verifies if the process is really tail recursive and will be compiled with tail-call optimization.

To EXERCISE 16: well, `map` do the job very well in scala. Well, you could also do it recursively, just to test yourself.

To EXERCISE 18: Same here, you should reimplement Map for list. A good inspiration point for this is always to check the original implementation of scala map. Anyway, you would be good by implementing a recursive solution where you apply `f` in each recursion step to the element and adding it into your accu.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score -1):

To add to @Mika'il's answer that gives you nice answers for exercises 16 and 18. You could use `flatten` to create a single `List` instead of folding it. `List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)).flatten` produces `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`; and `flatMap` if you need provide some transformations along the way. In fact, `flatMap` is equivalent to calling `map` and then `flatten`.

Comment: I think the purpose of a programming assignment is not to explore scala"s rich functionality but more to build them by himself.

Comment: And that's what I tried to do and asked for some tips on how to improve some of my own solutions... I just dont get all the downvotes always

Comment: @Allquantor007 OP said *try to use functions we have already defined*. Downvote for the sake of downvote without explanation brings nothing to the table.